# Is there a way to check if the user read FlowBot's MS Teams message in Power Automate?

Tags: power-automate

I've recently begun trying to work with Power Automate and I've stumbled upon an issue. I would like to detect in some way if a message that was automatically sent via the "Post message in a chat or channel" action has been read be the recipient. The message gets sent to a chat with FlowBot.
[image: "Post message in a chat or channel" action]
I tried using the "Get message details" action in hope that it might include this information. But it only looks like this:

```json
{
  "@odata.context": "[link]",
  "id": "1704376544642",
  "replyToId": "1704376544642",
  "etag": "1704376544642",
  "messageType": "message",
  "createdDateTime": "2024-01-04T13:55:44.642Z",
  "lastModifiedDateTime": "2024-01-04T13:55:44.642Z",
  "lastEditedDateTime": null,
  "deletedDateTime": null,
  "subject": null,
  "summary": null,
  "chatId": "[ID]",
  "importance": "normal",
  "locale": "en-us",
  "webUrl": null,
  "channelIdentity": null,
  "policyViolation": null,
  "eventDetail": null,
  "from": {
    "device": null,
    "user": null,
    "application": {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.teamworkApplicationIdentity",
      "id": "358f0194-6b0e-4dd3-af35-c24fe8a9ec87",
      "displayName": "Workflows",
      "applicationIdentityType": "bot"
    }
  },
  "body": {
    "contentType": "html",
    "content": "test message"
  },
  "attachments": [],
  "mentions": [],
  "reactions": [],
  "messageLink": "[link]",
  "threadType": "chat",
  "conversationId": "[ID]"
}
```

None of these keys look promising. Is this even supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware this is not tracked in this type of action.

As a workaround have you tried using the Post adaptive card and wait for a response action. Within that action you could create an adaptive card with a read receipt button (one simple button).

[image]

This way you the flow waits until the user clicks this button in your flow and that responses datetime will be the date you can use.

But just like with [e-mail receipts](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-and-request-read-receipts-and-delivery-notifications-in-outlook-for-windows-a34bf70a-4c2c-4461-b2a1-12e4a7a92141), it is no guarantee they have actually read the information though ;)

Comment: Alright. Thanks for answering the question and proposing an alternative. Maybe they will add this feature in the future.